# Trigger build from the secondary CodeCommit repo change

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have AWS CodePipeline setup that references CodeBuild project that specifies a secondary CodeCommit source. When I change code in the main CodeCommit project and push the changes the pipeline process is triggered and everything completes successfully. However changes (push) to the secondary CodeCommit project are simply ignored. Is there a way to trigger pipeline execution with changes to the secondary source(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy-peasy! Do not use a secondary source when using CodeBuild. Instead define 2 (or more) sources in the "Source" stage of the pipeline which will produce 2 (or more) input artifact. Then you can modify CodeBuild to refer to the 2nd artifact as `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_artifact_name` where `artifact_name` is the actual name you giving. Then the build is triggered by changes to both repos

Comment: I think you might have meant two sources (each producing a single output artifact). CodeCommit actions pull source from exactly one repo, but you can configure a pipeline with multiple source actions.

Comment: Sorry, I had to change CodeCommit to CodeBuild since that's what I had in mind. Thanks for pointing it out